# Protocols problems in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, menu, navigation, protocols

I'm implementing the RayWenderlich Slide out Navigation Panel: http://www.raywenderlich.com/78568/create-slide-out-navigation-panel-swift

And I want to open a new view ont Imageview tap like if I was clicking on the menu:

[image]

- Link 2: NosOffres
- Link 1: (index) Accueil (here is the Imageview)

**Problem:**

- **If I go in Link 2 from the Navigation/Menu, I can re-open the Navigation/Menu by slide or icon menu tap**
- **If I go in Link 2 from the Image View, I can re-open the Navigation/Menu by slide *but not with by icon menu tap***

I tried many solutions and asked here for help but no way to have a response, now I tried an another thing, but I have a protocol problem:

I can't redeclare a protocol (in CenterViewController.swift), so I don't know how to do:

CenterViewController.swift:

```
@objc protocol CenterViewControllerDelegate {
    optional func toggleLeftPanel()
    optional func collapseSidePanels()
}

protocol CenterViewControllerDelegate {
    func itemSelected(item: AccueilItem)
}

class CenterViewController: UIViewController {

    var delegate: CenterViewControllerDelegate?
    var menus: Array<Menu>!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor(red: 38.0/255.0, green: 51.0/255.0, blue: 85.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "Gotham", size: 13)!, NSForegroundColorAttributeName : UIColor.whiteColor()]
        self.title = "ACCUEIL"
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    @IBAction func menuTapped(sender: AnyObject) {
        delegate?.toggleLeftPanel?()
    }



    @IBAction func nosOffresTapped(sender: AnyObject) {
        print("lol")

        delegate?.itemSelected(AccueilItem(rawValue: "NosOffres")!)
    }

}


enum AccueilItem: String {
    case Accueil
    case NosOffres
    case DemandeGratuite
    case ContactezNous
    case Actualites
    case MentionsLegales

    func viewController() -> UIViewController {
        switch (self) {
        case Accueil: return UIStoryboard.centerViewController()!
        case NosOffres: return UIStoryboard.nosOffresViewController()!
        case DemandeGratuite: return {
            let vc = UIViewController();
            vc.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.orangeColor();
            return vc
            }()
        case ContactezNous: return UIStoryboard.nosOffresViewController()!
        case Actualites: return UIStoryboard.nosOffresViewController()!
        case MentionsLegales: return UIStoryboard.nosOffresViewController()!
        }
    }
}


private extension UIStoryboard {
    class func mainStoryboard() -> UIStoryboard { return UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: NSBundle.mainBundle()) }

    class func leftViewController() -> SidePanelViewController? {
        return mainStoryboard().instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("LeftViewController") as? SidePanelViewController
    }

    class func centerViewController() -> CenterViewController? {
        return mainStoryboard().instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("CenterViewController") as? CenterViewController
    }

    class func nosOffresViewController() -> NosOffresViewController? {
        return mainStoryboard().instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("NosOffresViewController") as? NosOffresViewController
    }

}
```

NosOffresViewController.swift:

```
@objc
protocol NosOffresViewControllerDelegate {
    optional func toggleLeftPanel()
    optional func collapseSidePanels()
}

class NosOffresViewController: UIViewController {

    var delegate: NosOffresViewControllerDelegate?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor(red: 38.0/255.0, green: 51.0/255.0, blue: 85.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "Gotham", size: 13)!, NSForegroundColorAttributeName : UIColor.whiteColor()]
        self.title = "NOS OFFRES"
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }
}
```

ContainerViewController.swift:

```
    enum SlideOutState{
        case BothCollapsed
        case LeftPanelExpanded
    }

    class ContainerViewController: UIViewController, CenterViewControllerDelegate, SidePanelViewControllerDelegate, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {

        var centerNavigationController: UINavigationController!
        var centerViewController: CenterViewController!

        var currentState: SlideOutState = .BothCollapsed

        var leftViewController: SidePanelViewController?

        let centerPanelExpandedOffset: CGFloat = 60

        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()

            centerViewController = UIStoryboard.centerViewController()
            centerViewController.delegate = self

            centerNavigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: centerViewController)
            view.addSubview(centerNavigationController.view)
            addChildViewController(centerNavigationController)

            centerNavigationController.didMoveToParentViewController(self)


            let panGestureRecognizer = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "handlePanGesture:")
            centerNavigationController.view.addGestureRecognizer(panGestureRecognizer)

        }
    }

    // MARK: CenterViewController delegate


    extension ContainerViewController {
        func itemSelected(item: MenuItem) {
            let vc = item.viewController()
            //create a new button
            let button: UIButton = UIButton(type: UIButtonType.Custom)
            //set image for button
            button.setImage(UIImage(named:"IconeMenu"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
            //add function for button
            button.addTarget(self, action: "toggleLeftPanel", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
            //set frame
            button.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0,30, 30)

            let barButton = UIBarButtonItem(customView: button)
            //assign button to navigationbar
            vc.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = barButton
            self.centerNavigationController.viewControllers = [vc]
            self.collapseSidePannels()
        }


        func nosOffresSelected(item: AccueilItem) {
            let vc = item.viewController()
            //create a new button
            let button: UIButton = UIButton(type: UIButtonType.Custom)
            //set image for button
            button.setImage(UIImage(named:"IconeMenu"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
            //add function for button
            button.addTarget(self, action: "toggleLeftPanel", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
            //set frame
            button.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0,30, 30)

            let barButton = UIBarButtonItem(customView: button)
            //assign button to navigationbar
            vc.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = barButton
            self.centerNavigationController.viewControllers = [vc]
            self.collapseSidePannels()
        }
    }

    extension ContainerViewController {

        func toggleLeftPanel() {
            let notAlreadyExpanded = (currentState != .LeftPanelExpanded)

            if notAlreadyExpanded {
                addLeftPanelViewController()
            }

            animateLeftPanel(shouldExpand: notAlreadyExpanded)
        }

        func collapseSidePannels() {
            switch (currentState) {
            case .LeftPanelExpanded:
                toggleLeftPanel()
            default:
                break
            }
        }

        func addLeftPanelViewController() {
            if (leftViewController == nil) {
                leftViewController = UIStoryboard.leftViewController()
                leftViewController!.menus = Menu.allMenu()

                addChildSidePanelController(leftViewController!)
            }
        }

        func addChildSidePanelController(sidePanelController: SidePanelViewController) {

            sidePanelController.delegate = self
            view.insertSubview(sidePanelController.view, atIndex: 0)

            addChildViewController(sidePanelController)
            sidePanelController.didMoveToParentViewController(self)
        }


        func animateLeftPanel(shouldExpand shouldExpand: Bool) {
            if (shouldExpand) {
                currentState = .LeftPanelExpanded

                animateCenterPanelXPosition(targetPosition: CGRectGetWidth(centerNavigationController.view.frame) - centerPanelExpandedOffset)
            } else {
                animateCenterPanelXPosition(targetPosition: 0) { finished in
                    self.currentState = .BothCollapsed

                    self.leftViewController!.view.removeFromSuperview()
                    self.leftViewController = nil;
                }
            }
        }

        func animateCenterPanelXPosition(targetPosition targetPosition: CGFloat, completion: ((Bool) -> Void)! = nil) {
            UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.8, initialSpringVelocity: 0, options: .CurveEaseInOut, animations: {
                self.centerNavigationController.view.frame.origin.x = targetPosition
                }, completion: completion)
        }

    }


    extension ContainerViewController {
        // MARK: Gesture recognizer

        func handlePanGesture(recognizer: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
            let gestureIsDraggingFromLeftToRight = (recognizer.velocityInView(view).x > 0)

            switch(recognizer.state) {
            case .Began:
                if (currentState == .BothCollapsed) {
                    if (gestureIsDraggingFromLeftToRight) {
                        addLeftPanelViewController()
                    }
                }
            case .Changed:
                if (((recognizer.view!.center.x + recognizer.translationInView(view).x) > view.center.x || gestureIsDraggingFromLeftToRight) && (recognizer.view!.center.x >= view.center.x && recognizer.velocityInView(view).x > 0 || recognizer.view!.center.x > view.center.x && recognizer.velocityInView(view).x < 0) && recognizer.view!.center.x + recognizer.translationInView(view).x > view.center.x) {
                    recognizer.view!.center.x = recognizer.view!.center.x + recognizer.translationInView(view).x
                    recognizer.setTranslation(CGPointZero, inView: view)
                }
            case .Ended:
                if (leftViewController != nil) {
                    // animate the side panel open or closed based on whether the view has moved more or less than halfway
                    let hasMovedGreaterThanHalfway = recognizer.view!.center.x > view.bounds.size.width
                    animateLeftPanel(shouldExpand: hasMovedGreaterThanHalfway)
                }
            default:
                break
            }
        }
    }


    private extension UIStoryboard {
        class func mainStoryboard() -> UIStoryboard { return UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: NSBundle.mainBundle()) }

        class func leftViewController() -> SidePanelViewController? {
            return mainStoryboard().instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("LeftViewController") as? SidePanelViewController
        }

        class func centerViewController() -> CenterViewController? {
            return mainStoryboard().instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("CenterViewController") as? CenterViewController
        }

        class func nosOffresViewController() -> NosOffresViewController? {
            return mainStoryboard().instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("NosOffresViewController") as? NosOffresViewController
        }

    }
```

SidePanelViewController.swift:

```
protocol SidePanelViewControllerDelegate {
    func itemSelected(item: MenuItem)
}

class SidePanelViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    var delegate: SidePanelViewControllerDelegate?

    var menus: Array<Menu>!

    struct TableView {
        struct CellIdentifiers {
            static let MenuCell = "MenuCell"
        }
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let tblView = UIView(frame: CGRectZero)
        tableView.tableFooterView = tblView
        tableView.tableFooterView!.hidden = true
        tableView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 71.0/255.0, green: 88.0/255.0, blue: 130.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
}

extension SidePanelViewController: UITableViewDataSource {
    func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 6
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(TableView.CellIdentifiers.MenuCell, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! MenuCell
        cell.configureForMenu(menus[indexPath.row])
        return cell
    }
}

// Mark: Table View Delegate

extension SidePanelViewController: UITableViewDelegate {
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        _ = menus[indexPath.row]
        delegate?.itemSelected(MenuItem(rawValue: indexPath.row)!)
    }
}


enum MenuItem: Int {
    case Accueil
    case NosOffres
    case DemandeGratuite
    case ContactezNous
    case Actualites
    case MentionsLegales

    func viewController() -> UIViewController {
        switch (self) {
        case Accueil: return UIStoryboard.centerViewController()!
        case NosOffres: return UIStoryboard.nosOffresViewController()!
        case DemandeGratuite: return {
            let vc = UIViewController();
            vc.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.orangeColor();
            return vc
            }()
        case ContactezNous: return UIStoryboard.nosOffresViewController()!
        case Actualites: return UIStoryboard.nosOffresViewController()!
        case MentionsLegales: return UIStoryboard.nosOffresViewController()!
        }
    }
}


class MenuCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!

    func configureForMenu(menu: Menu) {
        label.text = menu.title
    }

}


private extension UIStoryboard {
    class func mainStoryboard() -> UIStoryboard { return UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: NSBundle.mainBundle()) }

    class func leftViewController() -> SidePanelViewController? {
        return mainStoryboard().instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("LeftViewController") as? SidePanelViewController
    }

    class func centerViewController() -> CenterViewController? {
        return mainStoryboard().instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("CenterViewController") as? CenterViewController
    }

    class func nosOffresViewController() -> NosOffresViewController? {
        return mainStoryboard().instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("NosOffresViewController") as? NosOffresViewController
    }

}
```

I really don't know how to do here I tried to do the same thing of SidePanelViewController to CenterViewController, but I don't know if they're an another solution, help me please.

Comment: I don't understand very well what you're trying to achieve. You want to open the slideOutSideBar when the `UIImageView` is tapped?

Comment: @VictorSigler Yes, when I tap on my ImageView my View is opening, but when I tap on the Icone Menu in this view the Menu don't open, but if I slide left to the right it's opening.

Comment: @VictorSigler But If I access to this view from the menu the slide and the Icone Menu are working correctely

Comment: @VictorSigler Look my edit I did an abstract of the problem

Comment: Yeap, I understand, can you share your project in Github?

Comment: Yes wait, I hope you can help me 2 min I upload it

Comment: @VictorSigler here: https://github.com/benjyspider/Solutis  GitHub show a error but I think there all files

Comment: @VictorSigler Sorry if I did some changes on my code

Comment: Don't worry I'll check out now.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91854/discussion-between-victor-sigler-and-b-benj).

Answer (score 0):

Your problem resides in when you use the menu to show a new `UIViewController` you are manipulating the `navigationItem` in your `ContainerViewController` in this way:

```
 func itemSelected(item: MenuItem) {
    let vc = item.viewController()
    //create a new button
    let button: UIButton = UIButton(type: UIButtonType.Custom)
    //set image for button
    button.setImage(UIImage(named:"IconeMenu"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    //add function for button
    button.addTarget(self, action: "toggleLeftPanel", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
    //set frame
    button.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0,30, 30)

    let barButton = UIBarButtonItem(customView: button)
    //assign button to navigationbar
    vc.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = barButton
    self.centerNavigationController.viewControllers = [vc]
    self.collapseSidePannels()
}
```

And for the above code the `UINavigationController` remains the same when you open the `NosOffresViewController`.

One way to solve your problem is add a new method in your `CenterViewControllerDelegate` and call it before push the new `UIViewController` and pass the reference to it:

```
@objc protocol CenterViewControllerDelegate {
   optional func toggleLeftPanel()
   optional func collapseSidePanels()
   optional func pushViewControllerInStack(viewController: UIViewController)
}
```

Like the following way:

```
@IBAction func nosOffresTapped(sender: AnyObject) {
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(UIStoryboard.nosOffresViewController()!, animated: false)
    self.delegate?.pushViewControllerInStack!(UIStoryboard.nosOffresViewController()!)
}
```

And then in your `ContainerViewController` implements the method like in the following way:

```
func pushViewControllerInStack(viewController: UIViewController) {

    let vc = viewController
    //create a new button
    let button: UIButton = UIButton(type: UIButtonType.Custom)
    //set image for button
    button.setImage(UIImage(named:"IconeMenu"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    //add function for button
    button.addTarget(self, action: "toggleLeftPanel", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
    //set frame
    button.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0,30, 30)

    let barButton = UIBarButtonItem(customView: button)
    //assign button to navigationbar
    vc.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = barButton
    self.centerNavigationController.viewControllers = [vc]
    self.collapseSidePannels()
}
```

And this should work to present any new `UIViewController` from the `CenterViewController`.

I hope this help you.

Comment: There is a bug, if you access first from the imageView, and you tape on the IconMenu and go back to Accueil (index) you click again on the ImageView and tap on the IconMenu, my app is stopped, I'm looking at, do you know why it happen ?

Comment: Ok I've forgotten this:     `@IBAction func menuTapped(sender: AnyObject) {
        delegate?.toggleLeftPanel?()
    }` in NosOffresViewController but nothing happen (my app still running), `delegate?.toggleLeftPanel?()` don't work

Comment: I have 3 extensions:

`extension ContainerViewController: CenterViewControllerDelegate, NosOffresViewControllerDelegate{
func: pushViewControllerInStack, toggleLeftPanel, collapseSidePannels, addLeftPanelViewController, addChildSidePanelController, animateLeftPanel, animateCenterPanelXPosition}

extension ContainerViewController: SidePanelViewControllerDelegate{
func: itemSelected}

extension ContainerViewController{
func: handlePanGesture}`

But same bug

Comment: @B.Benj Please see the repo in Github https://github.com/Vkt0r/SlideOutSideBarTest and let me know if you have any doubt.

Comment: Thanks for response, you have the same error, repeat theses actions: tap on ImageView, (your in nowOffres view) tap on the iconMenu and click on Accueil, do again these actions and on the second time an error will appear

Comment: I will not have access to my MAC Book for 2 weeks I hope you can add a response for this problem, I'll learn it in two weeks, thanks for you help

Comment: Yes , don't worry I'll have soon an answer for you problem.

Comment: Hi @VictorSigler have you found the problem please

Comment: I see a new commit in your repository I'mgonna test it if you did some changes, I tried to find the problem I try to do something with UITapGestureRecognizer on this button, I don't know if it's the good way to resolve

Comment: I see the problem, I just played with the sizes of iconeMenu, and when I run my apps before the app crashes, it's the IconeMenu of the view, and not the IconeMenu of pushViewControllerInStack

Comment: I get the problem ! I did a breakpoint on this line: `self.delegate?.pushViewControllerInStack!(UIStoryboard.nosOffresViewController()!)` and one in the function pushViewControllerInStack And when I do maniplations, my app read this line `self.delegate?.pushViewControllerInStack!(UIStoryboard.nosOffresViewController()!)` but it don't go in the function.

Comment: I think I have a solution, on the menu, instead of call centerViewController on Accueil I have to call the containerViewController no ?

Comment: Hi can you delete the repository of git please ? thank you